# Not able to create React native app using React native version 0.69.0

Tags: react-native

I have tried to install app using

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
```

But it has just created package and node module files and not created Platform-specific folders like android and ios.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try rerunning this command in another folder.
2. Check if there any errors in terminal where you ran that command